# pywinauto error in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pywinauto

I have installed "pywinauto" in Python 3.4.1 32 bit (on a Windows 7 64 bit machine) using the command:

```
pip.exe install pywinauto
```

which gave me the following output:

> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip.exe install pywinauto Downloading/unpacking
>   pywinauto   Running setup.py
>   (path:C:\Users\arun_m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_arun_m\pywinauto\setup.py)
>   egg_info for package pywinauto
>
> Installing collected packages: pywinauto   Running setup.py install
>   for pywinauto
>         File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\clipboard.py", line 94
>           print formats
>                       ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py",
> ```
>
> line 356
>           print "##### not dealing with that TVN_GETDISPINFO stuff yet"
>                                                                       ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py",
> ```
>
> line 461
>           print "dialog not found"
>                                  ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\wraphandle.py", line
> ```
>
> 43
>           except AttributeError, e:
>                                ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line
> ```
>
> 39
>           print "blah"
>                      ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 137
>     _after_tab = re.compile(ur"\t.*", re.UNICODE)
>                                    ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 221
>     print "==" * 20
>              ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py", line 323
>     print "%15s\t%s" % (name, value)
>                    ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\tests\missingextrastring.py",
> ```
>
> line 160
>           print num_found, num_bugs, loc, ref
>                         ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\tests\__init__.py", line 79
>     print "BugType:", bug_type, is_in_ref,
>                    ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\test_application.py", line 36
>     app.connect_(path = ur"No process with this please")
>                                                       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32defines.py", line 50
>     HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 2147483648L # Variable POINTER(HKEY__)
>                                   ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32structures.py", line 43
>     print "%20s "% name, getattr(struct, name)
>                 ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```
>
> Successfully installed pywinauto Cleaning up...

After this, when I execute the following in Python's IDLE:

```
import pywinauto
```

it gives no error. But when I try:

```
from pywinauto import application
```

it gives me the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       from pywinauto import application   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 64, in
>   
>       import win32structures ImportError: No module named 'win32structures'

I searched in Python3.4 folder and found "win32structures.py" file in the location:

> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\

I don't know why it's giving "ImportError" when the file is present.

Can you please tell me what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official `pywinauto 0.4.2` version is compatible with 32-bit Python 2.x only. You can install `pywinauto` on `Python 2.7.8 32-bit`, for example (I use Python 2.6.6). Also you can find some unofficial modifications which are compatible with 64-bit Python 2.x (it's absolutely necessary for 64-bit apps automation). I didn't see Python 3.x compatible versions. Maybe you will be more lucky.

**EDIT:**

`pywinauto` project has been moved to [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto). It's `Python 3.x` compatible now. Use `64-bit` Python for `64-bit` apps and `32-bit` Python for `32-bit` ones.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried doing the following: `pip.exe install pywinauto` for Python 2.7.8 but it gives no message and doesn't install it. So I have downloaded the "pywinauto-0.4.2.zip" file and will try and install it using `python` command and let you know how it went. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion worked! I installed the following package:

> SendKeys-ctypes-0.2

and then installed **pywinauto** in Python 2.7.8. "pywinauto" seems to be working just fine!!